# Nvdia Multiple Monitors Issues

Tags: rhel, display

I am attempting to set up a 3 screen monitor display on RHEL7. My current driver is Nvdia 340.102. When i initially changed the X server configuration file, i received an white error screen during reboot. The error message did however extend to all three monitors. With my system unable to display a interface, i ssh into it from another computer and attempted to trouble shoot the issue. I could not figure it out. The only progress i got was after commenting out (disabling) Xinerama. After doing that, i was able to boot into a interface, but only on my single middle main monitor. The additional monitors i added are completely black, however, i can move my mouse over to them, for which my curser turns from a pointer to a cross-hair.

Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

TrevorKS, have you tried using 2 monitors first? Also, are all 3 monitors on the same graphics card? I ran into issues with the second scenario when I was trying to use 3 Monitors where 2 where plugged into the graphics card and the 3rd was on the onboard display. I have it working right now with RHEL 7.4 using the default Novuea drivers.

Comment: Yes, all 3 monitors are coming into the video card into the same port. I am also using 7.4. but using Nvidia. Novuea drivers are blacklisted on our network, so not much of an option.

Comment: I'm in the opposite spectrum, I have Nouveau allowed but not Nvidia.. Sorry I can't test this with Nvidia and tell you if I experience the same thing.